How can i verify with Autodesk ACC APIs if a model is colaborative
I need to get if a revit model is colaborative in cloud using the APIs of Autodesk.

I tried to use the data management API but i don't find any attribute that brings me this information, i don't know if this parameter is in another API.

What does the text of your snapshot mean in English? Is it Workshared cloud  model?

@EasonKang yes , it's Workshared cloud model.

Please use Data Management API to get the item information with endpoint: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/
Check the property of data.attributes.extension.type, if the type is "items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel", it means it's a Revit Cloud Model. You can also find the projectGuid and modelGuid in the version body as follow
Revit Cloud Model Version Info
